# Irregular shapes in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

With Delphi, using Firemonkey:

How can I get a shape like in the drawing using TShape components?
I do not want to use a bitmap.

[image: Irregular shapes]

Comment: I don't know Firemonkey, but in VCL I'd just use a `TPaintBox` and write a few lines of code in its `OnPaint` handler.

Comment: Do you want to make your own component with a specific vector image on it? or do you just want to make a custom drawing in one place? In the latter case you can just use TPaintBox and assign the OnPaint. To draw, I would use a TPath

Comment: Use a Tpath component from Fmx.Objects unit. In its properties you will find a data of type TPathdata. Here you can define the shape of your shape:http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Graphics.TPathData.Data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a TPath component with the following path data should give you a result that's very similar to what you want:
M0,0 L100,0 C110,-5 110,-15 120,-20 L200,-20 C210,-15 210,-5 220,0 L320,0 L320,5 L0,5 Z

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you.